# Why is this PHP function not passing all variable data?

Tags: php, mysql, categories, interspire-shopping-cart

I'm battling it out with the Interspire shopping cart and my dodgy coding skills once again. :)

My goal is to create a category listing similar to the category block on the front page of BHphotovideo.com (lofty huh?). :) I believe this is a feature that comes with even free shopping carts but does not come pre-built in ISC. I just want a clickable list of all the top level categories with subcategories underneath the parent categories. The code below works great when I paste it into a blank php file but I need to integrate this into ISC so the links are click-able and the listing is a panel:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$cn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mydbuser", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());

$rs = mysql_query("SELECT categoryid, catparentid, catname FROM isc_categories", $cn) 
or die(mysql_error());

  $childrenTree = array(); //Will store an array of children for each parent
  $categoryNames = array(); //Will store category name for each id

//We fill $childrenTree and  $categoryNames from database
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
 list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $row;     
 $categoryNames[(string)$id] = $category;
 $parent_id = (string)$parent_id;
 if(!array_key_exists($parent_id, $childrenTree)) 
     $childrenTree[$parent_id] = array();
 $childrenTree[$parent_id][] = (string)$id;
}


//Main recursive function. I'll asume '0' id is the root node
 function renderTree($parent = "0"){
global $categoryNames;
global $childrenTree;
if($parent != "0") echo "<li> ", $categoryNames[$parent], "\n";
$children = $childrenTree[$parent];
if(count($children) > 0){ //If node has children
   echo "<ul>\n";
   foreach($children as $child)
      renderTree($child);
   echo "</ul>\n";
 }
 if($parent != "0") echo "</li>\n";
 }
 renderTree();  //This renders the hierarchical tree
?>
```

Below is my last (of many) attempts to get this code integrated as a standalone ISC panel. I just don't know where else to go with this.  The error I'm getting with the code below is: Notice: Undefined variable: childrenTree in /includes/display/HomeCategoryList.php on line 31

But childrenTree is defined in the _getcats function as is $categorynames which the script doesn't complain about so I would think it passed the data for $categorynames but not $childrenTress to the renderTree function. Is this correct?

Also for the original code the function _getcats doesn't exist and isn't necessary but the script below to add it to a panel forced me to put that bit of code into a function. Also if I change the database query syntax to match what is typically used in other ISC files, the script complains about undefined variables for this line: list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $row.  I don't know why that would be when the query should return the same results.

```
<?php

CLASS ISC_HOMECATEGORYLIST_PANEL extends PANEL
{
    public function SetPanelSettings()
    {
    $GLOBALS['SideCategoryListTypeClass'] = 'SideCategoryListClassic';
    $GLOBALS['SNIPPETS']['HomeCategoryList'] = $this->renderTree();
    }

    function _getcats(){
    $rs = mysql_query("SELECT categoryid, catparentid, catname FROM isc_categories") 
            or die(mysql_error());

      $childrenTree = array(); //Will store an array of children for each parent
      $categoryNames = array(); //Will store category name for each id

       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
               list($id, $parent_id, $category) = $row;     
               $categoryNames[(string)$id] = $category;
               $parent_id = (string)$parent_id;
               if(!array_key_exists($parent_id, $childrenTree)) 
               $childrenTree[$parent_id] = array();
               $childrenTree[$parent_id][] = (string)$id;
                }
              }

     function renderTree($parent = "0"){
           $this->_getcats();
        if($parent != "0")echo "<li> ", $categoryNames[$parent], "\n";
        $children = $childrenTree[$parent];
        if(count($children) > 0){ //If node has children
           echo "<ul>\n";
           foreach($children as $child)
              renderTree($child);
           echo "</ul>\n";
        }
        if($parent != "0") echo "</li>\n";
        }

        }
```

If you see anything right off the bat, I've overlooked or think you might know what the problem is, please point me in the right direction. I've been at this for days. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious problem I am seeing with the second part of the code is in the way you have defined $childrenTree and $categoryNames. You define them in _getcats() locally but then you invoke them from renderTree(). You should either change _getcats() to return a new array containing the two (tree/names) or declare them private in the class and call them like so.

i.e.

```
CLASS ISC_HOMECATEGORYLIST_PANEL extends PANEL
{
    private $categoryNames = array();
    private $categoryTree = array();

    private function _getCats() {
       ...
       $this->categoryNames[(string)$id] = $category;
       ...
       if(!array_key_exists($parent_id, $this->childrenTree)) 
         $this->childrenTree[$parent_id] = array();

       $this->childrenTree[$parent_id][] = (string)$id;
       ...
    }

    public function renderTree($parent = "0") {
       // Call childrenTree/categoryNames by using the $this directive again
    }
}
```

Btw if the above snippet of code is your coding style (and not an issue with pasting your code on stackoverflow) you should probably change it.